# JQuery does not remove "dIsplay:hidden" at all

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

List of things I tried

- .removeClass and addClass
- show() and hide();
- changing the css

To begin: Yes, I  do have onLoad in the beginning of my script, and all of the other components work perfectly. Yes, I have tried Googling, and nothing   fixes the problem. This is not a dublicate.

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $("block").addClass("hidden"); //class hidden is display: none
  $("block").removeClass("hidden");
}
```

This is my code. No, block is not a class or ID,  I am gonna use it as an example.
Please help, I do not know what I have done wrong in my code and why this doesn't work.

By the way, adding the class works, removing it doesn't.

HTML:

```
<block>A</block>
```

Comment: Could you provide the complete HTML and CSS code as well as JS code? It might be hard that reproduce the problem if you don't provide the HTML and CSS code.

Comment: please share the html

Comment: I have provided the html.

Answer (score 0):

is the event being triggered ? i know that `click` is depricated but it should be supported for compatibility , you can also print the button and look if the class is still there, the proper way should be using `on`

```
$("button").on("click", function () {
  $("block").addClass("hidden"); //class hidden is display: none
  $("block").removeClass("hidden");
  console.log($("block")) //look for classList
})
```

if you just want to hide a element you can also use

```
$("block").hide()
$("block").show()
```

or with fade in/out

```
$("block").fadeOut(500) // number of ms 
$("block").fadeIn(500)
```

one more thing in case you're confusing css properties and classes, a css property can be changed using `css`

```
$("block").css({display:"hidden"})
$("block").css({display:"block"})
```

Comment: I have said that I tried show() and hide()

Comment: Yes  it is being triggered.

Comment: I also tried css. Please look at the list of the things I tried.

Comment: @dudewholikescheese does it still have the class ? when checking the element

Comment: Yes, unfortunately the hide() and removeClass() functions don't work for some reason...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are aiming at?

```js
$("button").on("click",function(){
 $("block").toggleClass("hidden")
})
```

```css
.hidden { visibility: hidden }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<block>A</block>
<button>hide/show</button>
```

Instead of `display` I used the `visibilty` attribute to make sure nothing moves around. The jQuery method `.toggleClass("hidden")` then adds or removes the class "hidden".

And, since you actually *want* to see things moving around, you can do this:

```js
$("button").on("click",function(){
 $("block").toggleClass("hidden")
})
```

```css
.hidden { display: none }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<block>A</block>
<button>hide/show</button>
```

**Hint**: In a real application you should probably make the selector `"block"` a bit more specific. With the current script version *all* `<block>` elements will be affected. A lightweight way of targeting *only* the element that comes before the button would be to use something like `$(this).previous()`.

Comment: .toggleClass doesn't work. I want to use display so it moves around

Comment: Well, if you *want* things moving around then use my second snippet. ;-)

Comment: .toggleClass() does not work

Comment: Well, it _does_ in this snippet :D ...  If you have a problem in your particular environment then maybe you can share a little bit more of your code? An [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is always a good starting point.